# Error while counting instances of False in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe called p as follows

```
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8    True
9    True
dtype: bool>
```

and the relevant part of my code is as follows

```
count=(p.value_counts().loc[False])
```

I get an error with the above code. I am trying to count the number of occurrences of False in the dataframe.

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it? False is not in the dataframe so the answer should be 0?

The error looks like this

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1124, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1073, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3739, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: False
```

Comment: Try `count = p.value_counts().eq(False).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `p` is actually a Series (column), not a whole DataFrame (Table). In that case, to count the number of `False` values, you could easily do this:

```
count = p.eq(False).sum()
```

Comment: Actually I should have corrected myself earlier.
I tested the following series

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
dtype: bool

and got an answer of 0 when the answer should have been 8.

But 

count = p.eq(False).sum()

gives the correct answer thanks.

Comment: Yeah, after writing this answer I though that the code I send earlier wouldn't work actually.